# Face Traking Error Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to create a program on opencv for eyes tracking. However, the program often crashes for no apparent reason, especially when I cover my right eye with my hand.
I use code blocks and opencv 2.4.5

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int lar,hau;
Rect rect;
Mat copie_frame;
Mat carre;
Mat YCR;
Mat eye(lar,hau,CV_8UC1);

/** Function Headers */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );
void eyestreatment (Mat carre);
/** Global variables */
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;

string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
RNG rng(12345);

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* capture;
    Mat frame;

    //-- 1. Load the cascades
    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){
        printf("--(!)Error loading\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ 
        printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); 
        return -1; 
    }

    //-- 2. Read the video stream
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
    if( capture )
    {
        while( true )
        {
            frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

            //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
            if( !frame.empty() ){ 
                detectAndDisplay( frame ); 
            }
            else { 
                printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!"); 
                break; 
            }

            int c = waitKey(10);
            if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/** @function detectAndDisplay */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;

    cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

    //-- Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

    for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
    {
        Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
        Point haut((center.x+faces[i].width*0.5),(center.y+faces[i].height*0.5));
        Point bas((center.x-faces[i].width*0.5),(center.y-faces[i].height*0.5));

        Point pt=bas;
        int X=pt.x;
        int Y=pt.y;
        int L=haut.x-X;
        int H=haut.y-Y;
        rectangle(frame,haut,bas,Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ),1,8,0);

        Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
        std::vector<Rect> eyes;

        //-- In each face, detect eyes
        eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

        for( int j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
        {
            Point center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
            Point haut((center.x+eyes[i].width*0.5),(center.y+eyes[i].height*0.5));
            Point bas((center.x-eyes[i].width*0.5),(center.y-eyes[i].height*0.5));
            pt=bas;
            int X=pt.x;
            int Y=pt.y;
            int L=haut.x-X;
            int H=haut.y-Y;

            rectangle(frame,haut,bas,Scalar( 0, 255, 0 ),1,8,0);
            rect = Rect (bas.x,bas.y,L,H);
            carre= frame(rect);
            lar=carre.rows;
            hau=carre.cols;
            eyestreatment(carre);
        }
    }
    imshow( window_name, frame );
}

/** @function eyestreatment */
void eyestreatment( Mat carre )
{
    cvtColor(carre,YCR,CV_BGR2YCrCb);
    inRange ( YCR, Scalar (20, 130, 70) , Scalar (255, 170, 130) , eye );

    imshow("carre",carre);
    imshow("YCR",eye);
    eye.release();
}
```

Comment: When you use your debugger, what line is it crashing on?

Comment: I can not.
as soon as the acquisition is done ​​the program crashes

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your nested loop in function `detectAndDisplay`. You have variable `i` looping over faces, and variable `j` looping over eyes. However, you have the lines:

```
Point haut((center.x+eyes[i].width*0.5),(center.y+eyes[i].height*0.5));
Point bas((center.x-eyes[i].width*0.5),(center.y-eyes[i].height*0.5));
```

Thus, if you ever have less eyes than you have faces, it'll crash on your access to `eyes[i]`, as you are indexing into your eyes with your face counter. Of course, even when it's not crashing the code is incorrect as a consequence of this.

Comment: think you for your help

Comment: @MahmoudJmour glad to hear it helped. If it answered your question, you can accept this answer so your question will be marked as answered.